# Add List of Class in another List of class in C#

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a class A, class B and class C.

Class A is as:

```
public class A
{
    public string ColA { get; set; }
}
```

Class B is as :

```
public class B
{
    public int ColB { get; set; }
    public List<A> a { get; set; }
}
```

Class C is as:

```
public class C
{
    public int ColC { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> b { get; set; }
}
```

My input data is:

```
 var ipData = new[]
    {
        new { ColC = 1, ColB = 101, ColA = "val1" },
        new { ColC = 1, ColB = 101, ColA = "val2" },
        new { ColC = 1, ColB = 102, ColA = "val3" },
        new { ColC = 1, ColB = 102, ColA = "val4" }
    };
```

I am unable to make List of Class A under List of Class B.

```
   var objC = new C();
   foreach(var data in ipData)
   {
         objC.ColC = data.ColC;
         var objB = new B();
         var lstB = new List<B>();
         var lstA = new List<A>();
         var objA = new A();
         objA.ColA = data.ColA;
         lstA.Add(objA);
         objB = new B { ColB = data.ColB, a = lstA };
         lstB.Add(objB);
         objC.b = lstB; 

   }
```

It will add for first row of data. But in second row want to add `objA` in `List<A>` for `val2` since, rest of the data is same. 
Now for third row need to add `objB` in `List<B>` for new value `102` and its corresponding `objA` i,e; `val3` and `val4`.

expected output is:

```
 Class C
 C => 1 , B => 101 , A => val1, val2
          B => 102 , A => val3, val4
```

Comment: Can you actually *show* what you want the output to look like? Also, you probably will need to group your data by common values first.

Comment: I want to pass my class C as model to view to pass this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with this what gives me my output.

```
        public class Student
        {
            public string sid { get; set; }
        }
        public class Strength
        {
            public int Str { get; set; }
            public List<Student> stu { get; set; }
        }
        public class Profile
        {
            public int name { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Strength> strength { get; set; }
        }


        public class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {

         var ipData = new[]
            {
                new { ColC = 1, ColB = 101, ColA = "val1" },
                new { ColC = 1, ColB = 101, ColA = "val2" },
                new { ColC = 1, ColB = 102, ColA = "val3" },
                new { ColC = 1, ColB = 102, ColA = "val4" }
            };
                var prof = new Profile();
                var stren = new List<Strength>();

                var dColB = ipData.Select(x => x.ColB).Distinct();
                foreach(var newval in dColB)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(newval);
                    var colval = ipData.Where(x => x.ColB == newval);
                    var stud = new List<Student>();
                    foreach(var nval in colval)
                    {
                        var stuval = new Student { sid = nval.ColA };
                        stud.Add(stuval);                   
                    }
                    var strval = new Strength{ Str = newval, stu = stud };
                    stren.Add(strval);
                }

                var dColC = ipData.Select(x => x.ColC).Distinct();
                foreach(var data in dColC)
                {
                    prof.name = data;
                    prof.strength = stren;                
                }
                Console.WriteLine(prof.name);
                foreach(var ss in prof.strength)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ss.Str);
                    foreach(var nn in ss.stu)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(nn.sid);                          
                    }
                }                  
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some Linq methods (GroupBy and Select) :

```
List<C> cList2 = ipData.GroupBy(x => x.ColC).Select(colC => new C
{
    ColC = colC.Key,
    b = colC.GroupBy(colB => colB.ColB).Select(colB => new B
    {
        ColB = colB.Key,
        a = colB.Select(colA => new A
        {
            ColA = colA.ColA
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```